# mongodb do I need a abortTransaction after commitTransaction that fails?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, commit, rollback

mongoose/mongodb node.js code:

```
session.commitTransaction(function(err, reply){
    if(err) {
       session.abortTransaction(); //Do I need this abort?
    }
}
```

Is there someone who can help me plz.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session.abortTransaction/#Session.abortTransaction) of mongodb about transactions and the example they provide.

You should use `session.abortTransaction();` after having an exception on a database request.

But no need after a `commit` rejection.

---

That said [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) do not have the `abortTransactions()`. So I guess it's not required.

---

```
// Runs the txnFunc and retries if TransientTransactionError encountered

function runTransactionWithRetry(txnFunc, session) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            txnFunc(session);  // performs transaction
            break;
        } catch (error) {
            // If transient error, retry the whole transaction
            if ( error.hasOwnProperty("errorLabels") && error.errorLabels.includes("TransientTransactionError")  ) {
                print("TransientTransactionError, retrying transaction ...");
                continue;
            } else {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Retries commit if UnknownTransactionCommitResult encountered

function commitWithRetry(session) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            session.commitTransaction(); // Uses write concern set at transaction start.
            print("Transaction committed.");
            break;
        } catch (error) {
            // Can retry commit
            if (error.hasOwnProperty("errorLabels") && error.errorLabels.includes("UnknownTransactionCommitResult") ) {
                print("UnknownTransactionCommitResult, retrying commit operation ...");
                continue;
            } else {
                print("Error during commit ...");
                throw error;
            }
       }
    }
}

// Performs inserts and count in a transaction
function updateEmployeeInfo(session) {
   employeesCollection = session.getDatabase("hr").employees;
   eventsCollection = session.getDatabase("reporting").events;

   // Start a transaction for the session that uses:
   // - read concern "snapshot"
   // - write concern "majority"

   session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "snapshot" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );

   try{
      eventsCollection.insertOne(
         { employee: 3, status: { new: "Active", old: null },  department: { new: "XYZ", old: null } }
      );

      // Count number of events for employee 3

      var countDoc = eventsCollection.aggregate( [ { $match:  { employee: 3 } }, { $count: "eventCounts" } ] ).next();

      print( "events count (in active transaction): " + countDoc.eventCounts );

      // The following operations should fail as an employee ``3`` already exist in employees collection
      employeesCollection.insertOne(
         { employee: 3, name: { title: "Miss", name: "Terri Bachs" }, status: "Active", department: "XYZ" }
      );
   } catch (error) {
      print("Caught exception during transaction, aborting.");
      session.abortTransaction();
      throw error;
   }

   commitWithRetry(session);

} // End of updateEmployeeInfo function

// Start a session.
session = db.getMongo().startSession( { mode: "primary" } );

try{
   runTransactionWithRetry(updateEmployeeInfo, session);
} catch (error) {
   // Do something with error
} finally {
   session.endSession();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but thought to provide some insights to new comers.

On MongoDB's [Retry transaction and commit operation example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#retry-transaction-and-commit-operation), they call `session.abortTransaction()` after `session.commitTransaction()`.

```
try {
    await commitWithRetry(session);
} catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw error;
}
```

Which comes in conflict with MongoDB's [abortTransaction specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst#aborttransaction), that states the following:

> It is only valid to call abortTransaction when the session is in the
>   "starting transaction" or "transaction in progress" state.
>
> If this session is in the "transaction committed" state, then drivers
>   MUST raise an error containing the message "Cannot call
>   abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction".
>
> When the session is in the "starting transaction" state, meaning, no
>   operations have been performed on this transaction, drivers **MUST NOT**
>   run the abortTransaction command.

So I guess the answer to your question is, you shouldn't. Otherwise you will get error: `Cannot call abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction`.

Comment: Is it possible to check the state of the transaction before attempting to abort it? Otherwise I'm not sure how to handle rejections when abortTransaction fails in the catch block, other than nesting another try-catch within the catch block (which doesn't seem very elegant).

Comment: @AnthonyYershov You can check the state of the session `session.transaction.state` if it equals to "TRANSACTION_IN_PROGRESS".